# typescript 1+1 = 11 not 2

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a TypeScript class without any import statement at the top. When I new calculateDate() and execute addMonth(new Date(), 1), it adds 11 months to today instead of 2.  The m variable is always a result of string concatenation, instead of math addition operation. I even tried parseInt() with the string form of the two operands, it still performs string concatenation. Please help.  Thanks.

```html
export class calculateDate {

  addMonth(thisDate:Date, monthCount:number){
    if (thisDate && monthCount && monthCount != -1) {
      let m : number = thisDate.getMonth() + monthCount;

      console.log('m=', m);
      let newDate: Date = new Date(thisDate.setMonth(m));

      return newDate;
    }
    else
      return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `m = parseInt(month) + parseInt(thisDate.getMonth());`

Comment: the editor complains that number inside parseInt() can't be number..

Comment: Sounds very strange. If thisDate is a Date then getMonth() is an int - if monthCount is a number then it is also an int (or a float)

Comment: It really should not be necessary to cast any of them, but try `+monthCount + thisDate.getMonth()`

Comment: Please `console.log("date",thisDate);console.log("count",monthCount,typeof monthCount);console.log("m",m);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding up two strings, try to parse them as int or use this syntax `+thisDate.getMonth() + (+monthCount)`

Comment: ah. It worked using Fabio Carpinato's suggestion.   It's not very intuitive.  Thank you very much.

Comment: The method `getMonth()` on a `Date` returns an integer number, it is not necessary to cast it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth